# Can't connect from certain phone to certain server on certain WiFi network, everything else works and other phones work

Tags: android, http, wifi

I'm stuck on a difficult one here, if Stack Overflow is not the proper place for this type of question please advise on a different resource, but I'm not sure where else I would ask.

I'm using a relatively standard phone, Verizon Galaxy S4, not rooted and nothing unusual installed.  After connecting to a certain WiFi network at my workplace, I should be able to send http GET and POST requests to a certain server running a REST API host program.

Problem is, even when connected to this certain WiFi network, this one phone can't reach the server.  I've tried two different browsers (Chrome and the Samsung "Internet" browser) and two different REST API Android apps ("HTTP Client" and "REST Client for Android"), all say "can't connect to server" or similar.

Using anybody else's phone in the office, and executing the same simple http GET request to test communication, when on the certain WiFi network the other phones can communicate with the server.

When using the phone experiencing the difficulty connecting to the certain server, and when on or not on the certain WiFi network, everything else works (internet/phone calls/GPS functionality/anything else).

If I ask the network admins here, they will most likely say since every other phone can reach the certain server when on the certain WiFi network, that it's a phone problem not a network problem.  If I contact Verizon or Samsung, they will most likely say they do not support connectivity on the proprietary network where I work, and that since everything else on the phone works and it works on every other network, that it's a network problem and to contact the network admin.

I should also mention that I've checked the phone in question as far as security settings and similar, I turned off anything questionable and did not find anything unusual.

Can anybody suggest further troubleshooting direction?  Most of the tools out there (ex. Fiddler) run on the host, not a client phone, so I'm not sure what to do or check next.

Comment: Try to send request from Postman (chrome extension to test API's with GET or POST method). And check what are u getting.

Comment: Postman does not seem to be available for Android, so I tried two REST API Android clients, "HTTP Client" and "REST Client For Android", which should provide equivalent functionality.  On one I get "java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "(hostname)": No address associated with hostname", on the other I get "Connection Error - Host not found."  Any other suggested direction?

Comment: Can you test on destop???

Comment: Yes, I can get to the server from any desktop on the network using Postman or a browser, and I can get to the server when connected to the WiFi network on every other phone I've tried.  And everything else works on the phone in question, wheather connected to the certain WiFi network or not.

Comment: That API is hosted on local server or global server???

Comment: The server is within the company network, but any computer on the company network can get to it and so can any other phone when connected to the certain WiFi network.

Comment: If u r on same network then there is no issue.

Comment: The phone I need to get connected to the certain server will not connect to it, so there is definitely still an issue.